# I want to get '08-11-11' value from $each['added_on'] is it possible?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get specific value from `$each['added_on']`. Is it possible?

This is the code I am using.

```
$array = array();
$array[] = array('note' => 'asdf', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'abcd', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'qwer', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'zxcv', 'added_on' => '08-11-11');

foreach ($array as $each) {
   print_r($each['added_on']);
}

foreach ($each['added_on'] as $value) {
    print_r($value[0]);
}
```

Comment: Nope, it is not.

Comment: Never post code images, paste code into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way is with a classic IF:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = array('note' => 'a', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'b', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'c', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'd', 'added_on' => '08-11-11');

foreach ($array as $entry) {
    if ($entry['added_on'] == '08-11-11') {
        echo "its a match";
    }
}
```

You can do this without any IF or FOREACH, but you can never be sure you get the correct result. Use this only if the array never changes:

```
var_dump($array[3]['added_on']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

**check working demo here**: https://eval.in/868516

```
$array = array();

$array[] = array('note' => 'test', 'added_on' =>'15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'test', 'added_on' =>'15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'test', 'added_on' =>'15-11-11');
$array[] = array('note' => 'test', 'added_on' =>'08-11-11');

echo('<pre>');
print_r($array);

$key = array_search('08-11-11', array_column($array, 'added_on')); // get key of value

echo $array[$key]['added_on']; // assuming positive result
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
  $array = array();
  $array[] = array('note' => 'a', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
  $array[] = array('note' => 'b', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
  $array[] = array('note' => 'c', 'added_on' => '15-11-11');
  $array[] = array('note' => 'd', 'added_on' => '08-11-11');

  foreach ($array as $entry) {
    if($entry['added_on'] == '08-11-11'){
        echo $entry['added_on'];
     }
  }
?>
```